# How to insert SESSION_id on table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-insert

I need help to insert into my database league using a slash

```php
if(isset($_POST['selecionar']))
{
    $queryselect=sprintf("INSERT INTO league
                             (users_user_id)
                            VALUES
                             ( '{$_SESSION['user_id']}')",
                                mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['selecionar'])
                             );
    mysqli_query($link, $queryselect);
```

[...]

```
<form id='alterar_selecionar' method='POST'>                                          
    <input type='hidden' name='selecionar' value=<?php echo "'" . $row['id'] . "'"; ?> />
    <input type="submit" onClick="return confirm('Tem a certeza que deseja cancelar esta reserva ?')" value='Selecionar' />
</form>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How about use PDO conection?

Comment: what is PDO? Well i only need help in "  <form id='alterar_selecionar' method='POST'>
  
                                                    
  <input type='hidden' name='selecionar' value=<?php echo "'" . $row['id'] . "'"; ?> />
   
                                                     <input type="submit" onClick="return confirm('Tem a certeza que deseja cancelar esta reserva ?')" value='Selecionar' />
                                                    </form> "

Comment: help me please i need assistance

Comment: From the code you posted, I can't quite figure out what you're trying to do. Could you please post the *complete* text of any error messages you're getting? Also, you  should be using a prepared statement for this, but let's concentrate one problem at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the question you ask is that you want to insert "league using a slash" into your database. I noticed that the name of your MySQL table is league, and there appears to be a / at the end of your hidden HTML input.

```
<input type='hidden' name='selecionar' value=<?php echo "'" . $row['id'] . "'"; ?> />
```

The way I am interpreting this is that you want to insert the ID number and a slash into your MySQL table named league.  If I am interpreting this correctly, then I think what you are missing here are single quotes in the value section of your hidden input type. Notice you do have single quotation marks in type='hidden' and name='selectinar' but there are no single quotes around the value.  In the following code, I just placed single quotes around the value field.

```
    <input type='hidden' name='selecionar' value='<?php echo "'" . $row['id'] . "'"; ?> /'>
```

It might also be helpful to create a variable named $id to help make this PHP a bit easier to comprehend and read.

```
<?php 
$id = $row['id'];
echo "<input type='hidden' name='selecionar' value='$id/'>";
?>
```

I still am not sure if I truly understand your objective here, but perhaps something along these lines makes sense.

**PHP to get the id and then echo the $id in the HTML form with the /**

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('ip_or_domain', 'username', 'password', 'db');
$getid = "select id from tablename where something='something' ");
$query = mysqli_query($con, $getid);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$id = $row['id'];
}
?>

<form id='alterar_selecionar' method='POST'>                                          
<input type='hidden' name='selecionar' value='<?php echo $id; ?>/'>
<input type="submit" onClick="return confirm('Tem a certeza que deseja cancelar esta reserva ?')" value='Selecionar' />
</form>
```

**PHP MySQL Insert**

```
<?php
$selecionar = $_POST['selecionar'];
$con = new mysqli('ip_or_domain', 'username', 'password', 'db');
$insert = "insert into league (users_user_id) values ('$selecionar')";
$con->query($insert);
?>
```

Comment: My friend he is also need to insert record

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation devpro.  I have edited my post to include an insert as well :)

Comment: Thank you for the words of encouragement devpro =^..^=

Answer (score 0):

I cant figure out 100% what is actually want but if you just want to insert session id in yout table when selecoinar not empty than you can try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$sessionID = $_SESSION['user_id'];
if(intval($_POST['selecionar'])> 0){
    $queryselect="INSERT INTO league
                             (users_user_id)
                            VALUES
                             (".$sessionID.")";

    mysqli_query($link, $queryselect);
}// IF END


}// MAIN IF END
```

In HTML add button name="submit"

```
<input type="submit" onClick="return confirm('Tem a certeza que deseja cancelar esta reserva ?')"  name="submit" value='Selecionar' />
```